# Exhaustively intersect 2 or more lists of integer vectors

Tags: r, list

Is there a way to exhaustively intersect 2 or more lists of integer vectors in R without using `for` loops?  Example for the 2 list (3x2) case:

```
set.seed(7)
x <- 1:25
x1 <- sample(x, 11)
x2 <- sample(x, 7)
x3 <- sample(x, 15)
list1 <- list(x1 = x1, x2 = x2, x3 = x3)

y <- 1:20
y1 <- sample(y, 13)
y2 <- sample(y, 10)
list2 <- list(y1 = y1, y2 = y2)
```

So intersect x1 with y1, y2; x2 with y1, y2;, x3 with y1, y2

Comment: First, why do you now want to use a for loop?

Comment: I only use `for` loops in R as a last result because they are messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `lapply()`:

```
lapply(list1, function(x) lapply(list2, function(y) intersect(x, y)))
```

Comment: This is the preferred solution because the generated list is 2 dimensional.  So the vectors can be referenced by their x, y indices..

Answer (score 2):

You can try the code below

```
> outer(list1, list2, Vectorize(intersect))
   y1        y2
x1 Integer,6 Integer,5
x2 Integer,4 Integer,4
x3 Integer,8 Integer,5
```

---

If you want to explicitly see the intersection, you can try

```
> outer(list1, list2, FUN = Vectorize(function(x, y) toString(intersect(x, y))))
   y1                           y2
x1 "2, 15, 8, 3, 20, 11"        "10, 19, 8, 21, 18"
x2 "20, 8, 15, 6"               "12, 19, 8, 18"
x3 "16, 4, 11, 6, 2, 20, 8, 15" "16, 21, 8, 23, 12"
```